# issue in saving image to mysql database . Program is running perfectly with no errors

Tags: mysql, sql, vb.net

```vb
Imports MySql.Data.MySqlClient

Imports System.IO



Public Class Form1
    Dim connection As New MySqlConnection("server=Localhost;userid=root;password=root;database=image")

    Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

    End Sub

    Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

        Dim opf As New OpenFileDialog
        opf.Filter = "Choose Image(*.JPF;*.PNG;*.GIF)|*.jpg;*.png;*.gif"
        If opf.ShowDialog = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK Then
            PictureBox1.Image = Image.FromFile(opf.FileName)
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button2_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
        Dim command As New MySqlCommand("insert into saveimage(image) values(@img)", connection)
        Dim ms As New MemoryStream
        PictureBox1.Image.Save(ms, PictureBox1.Image.RawFormat)
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@img", SqlDbType.Image).Value = ms.ToArray()
        connection.Open()

        MessageBox.Show("Insert image")



    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: Does it recognise @img as a string?

Comment: What is the table definition? What happens when you retrieve it? If its running perfectly you wouldn't be asking a question I'd assume.

Comment: For future reference, a title and code is NEVER an adequate question. The title should summarise the issue and then the question should provide a FULL and CLEAR explanation of the problem, which must include the relevant code but must not be limited to that. If you can't be bothered posting a proper question, as described in the help centre, you'll likely find people can't be bothered answering your questions and they will be closed very quickly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is wrong:

```vb
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@img", SqlDbType.Image).Value = ms.ToArray()
```

You are mixing and matching two different ways of adding parameters.  If you call `AddWithValue` (which you generally should not) then you need to provide a value, not a type.  If you're going to specify a type and then set the `Value` afterwards then you call `Add`.

Also, `SqlDBType` is for `SqlClient` and SQL Server.  If you're using `MySqlClient` and MySQL then you need to use `MySqlDbType`.  That's a perfect example of why you need `Option Strict On` right there.

Your code should be something like this:

```vb
command.Parameters.Add("@img", MySqlDbType.Blob).Value = ms.ToArray()
```

I say "something like this" because what type you specify depends on the actual data type you used in the database.  If you need to use `VarBinary` then you should also specify a size.